# How to read a list of lists in python csv?

Tags: python, string, csv

I had written the 2d array(a list of lists) one of the columns of the CSV file. I want to read that column back to a 2d array(a list of lists). So I want to store the information I printed again to an array format.

"[[a,b],[c,d]]"

I want to store this as a 2d array [[a,b],[c,d]].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked in some other similar questions. So what I did is that I firstly took the text as it is and then check the instances of "[","]" and ",".The code is roughly as follows.

```
a="[[a,b],[c,d]"
without_brackets = a.replace('[','').split('],')
lists = [list(s.replace(']','').split(',')) for s in without_brackets]
```